# Computed property lookup seems to mutate a class/subtype

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, chromium

Given is the following code (detached from a larger program):

```js
class Sum extends Number {} {
  const Sum_ = Sum;

  Sum = function(n) {
    return new Sum_(n);
  };

  Sum.prototype = Sum_.prototype;
}

Sum.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = "Sum";

const dispatcher = (...args) => args.map(arg => {
  const tag = Object.prototype.toString.call(arg);
  return tag.slice(tag.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1, -1);
}).join("/");

const VALUE = Symbol("VALUE");

const foo = x => y => {
  if (x && x[VALUE] && (VALUE in x))
    x = x(y);

  else if (y && y[VALUE] && (VALUE in y))
    y = y(x);

  return dispatcher(x, y);
};

const bar = x => y => {
  if (typeof x === "function" && (VALUE in x)) // deviates
    x = x(y);

  else if (typeof y === "function" && (VALUE in y)) // deviates
    y = y(x);

  return dispatcher(x, y);
};

console.log("bar:", bar(Sum(2)) (Sum(3))); // "Sum/Sum"
console.log("bar:", bar(Sum(2)) (Sum(3))); // "Sum/Sum"
console.log("foo:", foo(Sum(2)) (Sum(3))); // "Sum/Sum"
console.log("foo:", foo(Sum(2)) (Sum(3))); // "Number/Number"
console.log("bar:", bar(Sum(2)) (Sum(3))); // "Number/Number"
```

As you can see, `foo`/`bar` are almost identical. Yet the first call to `foo` sort of mutates `Sum`'s prototype so that the `Object.prototype.toString` invocation  within `dispatcher` yields a different tag.

The computed property lookup `x[VALUE]` seems the decisive portion that causes the mutation. I have no clue what is happening here. Maybe...

- the problem is obvious, but after starring at the code for an hour I have no chance to see it anymore
- the mutation is caused by the `Sum` class
- it is a chromium/chrome related bug

As I understand it, `Sum` declares a class and the following block scope creates a reference copy and rebinds the class name with a function that eventually calls the class with `new`, so that `new` can be omitted on the calling side. However, I cannot see how this is related to the mutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this definitely is a bug. The minimal reproduction case I could write is

```js
class Sum extends Number {}
Sum.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = "Sum";

const VALUE = Symbol("VALUE");

function foo(x) {
  console.log("x.value", x[VALUE]);
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(x);
}

console.log("foo:", foo(new Sum(2))); // "[object Sum]"
console.log("foo:", foo(new Sum(2))); // "[object Number]"
```

I have no idea what is going wrong here, but I can only recommend not to extend the native primitive wrappers :-)
I did file https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=7706.

Comment: Thanks! I have a somehow difficult "relationship" with JS `class`es/subtyping anyway. Instead of being nostalgic I should just stop using it :D